# How can I index multiple columns in a nested loop?

Tags: r

I'm struggling to work out if it's possible to index multiple columns in a loop.

I have a nested 'for' loop in which I am assigning a value to a new column in a data frame based on the values in other columns.

The data frame is large (over 80,000 observations of over 6000 variables) and for one of the nested loops, I'd like to look over an index of columns (i.e. data[,46:6000])

So far I've tried:

```
# create example dataset:

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
capital1 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital2 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital3 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital4 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital5 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital6 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital7 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital8 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital9 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital10 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))

data <- data.frame(id, capital1, capital2, capital3, capital4,
capital5, capital6, capital7, capital8, capital9, capital10)

# create new column to populate with results of loop

nrows<-length(data[,1])

AFT<-rep("N_A",nrows)

# loop through an index of columns

for (i in c(1:nrows)) {
    if(AFT[i] == "N_A"){
        if(data[,6:10] >= 50){
        AFT[i] <- "aft.multi"}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to assign 'AFT' to 'aft.multi' wherever the value of each of the individual variables in columns 6:10 is greater than or equal to 50. I want to do this because in my actual data I need to look across a huge number of columns e.g. [,40:6000].

When I ran the code I received warnings ‘the condition has length greater than 1 and only the first element will be used’, which sounds like it doesn’t like the index?

I'd appreciate any advice on where I might be going wrong.

I understand I may need to use a row identifier too, but I'm not sure where to place this. For example in other loops in the next I have working code like this:

```
for (i in c(1:nrows)) {
    if(AFT[i] == "N_A"){
        if(data$capital1[i] >= 60){
        AFT[i] <- "aft.productive"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your conditional "data[,6:10] >= 50" actually creates a logical matrix of nrows(data) x 5, where it checks for each value if it is greater or equal than 50. I guess you are looking for something like all(data[i, 6:10]) which checks if the values in the column 6 to 10 of the current row are all greater or equal than 50!

Comment: Thanks @Ben373, I tried this and still received similar warning messages: e.g. 1: In if (data[i, 6:10] >= 50) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: thats why I wrote, "all(data[i, 6:10])". You probably forgot the all()

Comment: Ah, I did miss the all(). Thanks very much for your help - all() works but I've ended up using max() because I wanted to check if only one (not all) of the values in columns 6:10 are greater than or equal to 50.